# verbatim environment inside a tcolorbox results in misalignment

Tags: tcolorbox, verbatim, code

I'm trying to put two code examples in a `tcolorbox` side by side. The problem is that I am using the `alltt` environment a derivative of the `verbatim` environment.

Here is my code:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside,title=Exemple]
    On souhaite créer trois variables \verb~a~, \verb~b~ et \verb~c~ avec des chiffres puis faire des opérations dessus.
    \begin{alltt}
    {\color{green!50!black!}a} ← 2       (la variable a vaut 2)
    {\color{green!50!black!}b} ← 3       (la variable b vaut 3)
    {\color{green!50!black!}c} ← {\color{green!50!black!}a} + {\color{green!50!black!}b}
    {\color{red}afficher} {\color{green!50!black!}c}
    \(\Longrightarrow\) 5
    \end{alltt}
    \tcblower
    On souhaite créer deux variables \verb~prenom~ et \verb~nom~ avec du texte.
    \begin{alltt}
    {\color{green!50!black!}prenom} ← "Jean"
    {\color{green!50!black!}nom} ← "Jaurès"
    {\color{red}afficher {\color{green!50!black!}prenom} + {\color{green!50!black!}nom}}
    \(\Longrightarrow\) "Jean Jaurès"
    \end{alltt}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

And here is the result:

[image: problem with a tcolorbox]

As you can see the problem is that the second column doesn't start at the same level of the first one, it is lower. I think it is because of the `verbatim` environment (well the `alltt`) because when I delete it I don't have this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `sidebyside align=top`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{alltt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  sidebyside,
  sidebyside align=top,
  title=Exemple
]
  On souhaite créer trois variables \verb~a~, \verb~b~ et \verb~c~ avec
  des chiffres puis faire des opérations dessus.
  \begin{alltt}
  {\color{green!50!black!}a} ← 2       (la variable a vaut 2)
  {\color{green!50!black!}b} ← 3       (la variable b vaut 3)
  {\color{green!50!black!}c} ← {\color{green!50!black!}a} + {\color{green!50!black!}b}
  {\color{red}afficher} {\color{green!50!black!}c}
  \(\Longrightarrow\) 5
  \end{alltt}
  \tcblower
  On souhaite créer deux variables \verb~prenom~ et \verb~nom~ avec du texte.
  \begin{alltt}
  {\color{green!50!black!}prenom} ← "Jean"
  {\color{green!50!black!}nom} ← "Jaurès"
  {\color{red}afficher {\color{green!50!black!}prenom} + {\color{green!50!black!}nom}}
  \(\Longrightarrow\) "Jean Jaurès"
  \end{alltt}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, a better code would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{alltt}

\colorlet{one}{green!50!black!}
\colorlet{two}{red}
\newcommand{\OO}[1]{\textcolor{one}{#1}}
\newcommand{\TT}[1]{\textcolor{two}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  sidebyside,
  sidebyside align=top,
  title=Exemple
]
  On souhaite créer trois variables \verb~a~, \verb~b~ et \verb~c~ avec
  des chiffres puis faire des opérations dessus.
  \begin{alltt}
  \OO{a} ← 2       (la variable a vaut 2)
  \OO{b} ← 3       (la variable b vaut 3)
  \OO{c} ← \OO{a} + \OO{b}
  \TT{afficher} \OO{c}
  \(\Longrightarrow\) 5
  \end{alltt}
  \tcblower
  On souhaite créer deux variables \verb~prenom~ et \verb~nom~ avec du texte.
  \begin{alltt}
  \OO{prenom} ← "Jean"
  \OO{nom} ← "Jaurès"
  \TT{afficher} \OO{prenom} + \OO{nom}
  \(\Longrightarrow\) "Jean Jaurès"
  \end{alltt}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Rename `\OO`, `\TT`, `one` and `two` to be more semantic in your context.

Comment: Yes thanks. Noticed my mistake, I was using `valign=top` which didn't work.

Comment: @Nicryc I added some advice on how to improve your code.

Comment: Oh thanks, will use it.